# reusing Body in http.Requests (goproxy)

Tags: http, go

Goproxy is a Go package implementing an HTTP proxy.
I am using it to store requests from a client (eg: a web browser) for further processing.

In an `http.Request struct`, the `Body` is an `io.ReadCloser`, it can only be read once.

The problem I faced is that I need to read the Body to store it, but still make it accessible to goproxy so that it can be sent to the server.

I solved it by reading the body with `ioutil.ReadAll`, and then creating a   `ReadCloser` with the byte slice I got. I then assign this `ReadCloser` to the request `Body`.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "sync"

    "github.com/elazarl/goproxy"
)

var requests map[string][]Request
var mutex sync.Mutex

type Request struct {
    Method        string
    URL           url.URL
    Proto         string // "HTTP/1.0"
    ProtoMajor    int    // 1
    ProtoMinor    int    // 0
    Header        http.Header
    Body          []byte
    ContentLength int64
    Host          string
    PostForm      url.Values
    RequestURI    string
}

type RequestBody struct {
    *bytes.Reader
}

func (r RequestBody) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func storeRequest(r *http.Request, ctx *goproxy.ProxyCtx) (*http.Request, *http.Response) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        // only print error for now
        log.Println(err)
        return r, nil
    }
    r.Body.Close()
    r.Body = RequestBody{bytes.NewReader(body)}
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    mutex.Lock()
    requests[r.URL.Host] = append(requests[r.URL.Host], Request{
        Method:        r.Method,
        URL:           *r.URL,
        Proto:         r.Proto,
        ProtoMajor:    r.ProtoMajor,
        ProtoMinor:    r.ProtoMinor,
        Header:        r.Header,
        Body:          body,
        ContentLength: r.ContentLength,
        Host:          r.Host,
        PostForm:      r.PostForm,
        RequestURI:    r.RequestURI,
    })
    mutex.Unlock()
    return r, nil
}

func main() {
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.OnRequest(goproxy.ReqHostMatches(regexp.MustCompile("^.*$"))).
        HandleConnect(goproxy.AlwaysMitm)
    proxy.OnRequest().DoFunc(storeRequest)

    requests = make(map[string][]Request)

    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8080", "proxy listen address")
    flag.Parse()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, proxy))
}
```

I would like to know if this is a correct way of solving this problem.

Comment: It looks like you're caching solely based on URL. You should really be caching by method too. Actually, you probably should only be caching `HEAD` and `GET` requests. And you should probably be saving some of the request headers. `Accept-Language`, for example, can have an effect on the response. You should also be complying with `Cache-Control` response headers. I'm not sure how much of this goproxy does. It also isn't clear to me that your cache is ever used (it looks like you only store).

Comment: @BaileyParker that does not matter for as long he is not doing for cache management. surely he is not in regard to current source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to read the body and replace it, although see [ioutil.NopCloser](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser).

However,

- it does not make sense to duplicate the [http.Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) type. Re use it instead. If you need finer control, embed it.
- take care to make true copy when passing around slices, maps and pointers.
- the code is lacking structured factorization, make use of [type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) definition

This is a revised version i suggest,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "sync"

    "github.com/elazarl/goproxy"
)

type store struct {
    requests map[string][]http.Request
    sync.Mutex
}

func (s *store) Add(r *http.Request) {
    var c http.Request
    c.Method = r.Method
    c.Proto = r.Proto
    c.ProtoMajor = r.ProtoMajor
    c.ProtoMinor = r.ProtoMinor
    c.Host = r.Host
    c.RequestURI = r.RequestURI
    c.ContentLength = r.ContentLength
    c.URL = r.URL

    c.Header = http.Header{}
    for k, vv := range r.Header {
        for _, v := range vv {
            c.Header.Set(k, v)
        }
    }

    c.PostForm = url.Values{}
    for k, vv := range r.PostForm {
        for _, v := range vv {
            c.PostForm.Set(k, v)
        }
    }

    c.Form = url.Values{}
    for k, vv := range r.Form {
        for _, v := range vv {
            c.Form.Set(k, v)
        }
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&b, r.Body)
    r.Body.Close()
    buf := b.Bytes()

    var b1 bytes.Buffer
    b1.Write(buf)
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(&b1)

    c.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))

    key := r.URL.Host
    s.Lock()
    s.requests[key] = append(s.requests[key], c)
    s.Unlock()
}

type storeHandler struct {
    requests *store
}

func (s storeHandler) Handle(r *http.Request, ctx *goproxy.ProxyCtx) (*http.Request, *http.Response) {
    s.requests.Add(r)
    return r, nil
}

func main() {
    h := storeHandler{requests: &store{requests: map[string][]http.Request{}}}

    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.OnRequest(goproxy.ReqHostMatches(regexp.MustCompile("^.*$"))).
        HandleConnect(goproxy.AlwaysMitm)
    proxy.OnRequest().DoFunc(h.Handle)

    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8080", "proxy listen address")
    flag.Parse()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, proxy))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of your question:

> Is it allowed to change `Body` field value of `http.Request` struct?

Part of [http.Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) documentation:

```
// Body is the request's body.
//
// For client requests a nil body means the request has no
// body, such as a GET request. The HTTP Client's Transport
// is responsible for calling the Close method.
//
// For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil
// but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
// Handler does not need to.
Body io.ReadCloser
```

The documentation says nothing about it. So we need to find some top level policy on such things. As far as I know there is no one in Go documentation.

`Body` field type is `io.ReadCloser` interface, the actual struct type is hidden behind it.

- the actual type may have non exported fields which work in conjuction with `Close` method,
- the hidden struct may be part of some reusable pool and will be lost,
- [HTTP trailer headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer) may be somewhere behind EOF.

You may take a look at current [`net/http` sources](https://golang.org/src/net/http/) to find the answer, but it can change in next Go release.

So I guess your best bet is to ask the Go community or even propose a change to `Body` documentation that will clear things out.

---

Another approach would be to wrap original `Body` and read it together with request handler.